# Can't run primefaces 1.1 with JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-1.2

i am trying to use **primefaces 1.1** with **JSF 1.2**
by adding the jars to classpath since primefaces doesn't require any configuration and my jsp page is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsp:root version="1.2"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns:ui="http://www.sun.com/web/ui"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <f:view>
        <ui:page id="page1">
            <ui:html id="html1">

           <body id="body1">
                <ui:form binding="#{MyBean.gform}">
              <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="dlg1.show();" type="button" /> 

                        <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
                            <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
                        </p:dialog>
```

but i am getting script errors that `'PrimeFaces' is undefined`
please advise what's the problem.

**EDIT:**

when trying to use only the component `<p:spinner />` for testing as in the getting started
i got the error:

```
The value of the property 'jQuery' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want PrimeFaces to include his JavaScript and CSS files, you need to add `<p:resources />` to the `head`.

Comment: so i just add <p:resources /> tag only ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh With searching I've done, it looks like yes but I've not tested yet.